# dvipdfm.exe create a PDF file of 0 bytes

Tags: pdf, miktex, conversion, texniccenter, size

Why does dvipdfm.exe create a PDF file of 0 bytes, but dvipdfmx.exe creates a valid one?

Windows 10.
Latest version of MiKTeX setup-4.2-x64.exe (1/19/2021).
Latest version of [TeXnicCenter 2.02](http://sourceforge.net/projects/texniccenter/files/TeXnicCenter/2.02%20Stable/TXCSetup_2.02Stable_x64.exe/download).
Sample file from http://www.gust.org.pl/doc/1stdocument/latex.

Comment: There was a bug report about this at the texlive list from the miktex maintainer. It should be resolved soon, but imho dvipdfm is an alias anyway, so simply use dvipdfmx. See https://tug.org/pipermail/dvipdfmx/2021-March/000259.html